# Handling GotFocus / LostFocus events on all TextBoxes in a Form VB6

Tags: vb6, focus, handler

I would like to create a handler which listens `GetFocus` / `LostFocus` events for all `TextBoxes` in a `Form` using VB6 how can I achieve that?

What i tried so far:

```
Option Explicit
Dim Cnt As Control
Private WithEvents Txt As VB.TextBox

Private Sub Form_Load()
    For Each Cnt In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf Cnt Is TextBox Then
            Set Txt = Cnt
        End If
    Next Cnt
End Sub

Private Sub Txt_GotFocus()
    Txt.BackColor = &H80000018
End Sub

Private Sub Txt_LostFocus()
    Txt.BackColor = &H80000005
End Sub
```

but this only works for one `TextBox` in the `Form`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this only works for one TextBox in the Form`  because Txt can only refer to one textbox at a time.

One way to have a common handler is to create your Texboxes as a control array.  Give them all the same name (ie `txtBox`).  VB will automatically make an array of them.  You can control their order in the array using the Index property.  Now, your `LostFocus` will look like this:

```
Private Sub txtBox_LostFocus(Index As Integer)
    txtBox(Index).Backcolor = &H80000005
End Sub
```

If you need to change what you do based on WHICH textbox it is, use the `Index` to tell which one it is.  NOTE: Control arrays are quite handy, but they disappear in VB.NET.  There are some equivalent methods but I would not get too attached to the exact way they work.

For more complex ops, the several events can call a common procedure passing the control as an argument.